# How to pass parcelables through Navigation Deep Links?

Tags: android, navigation, android-deep-link

I am building a multi-modular project where I'll have a separated module only for navigation (`:navigation`). This module will be responsible for the navigation across modules and I'll be doing it by using deep links.

Is it possible to pass `Parcelable` arguments using navigation deep links?
If not, is there any other viable alternative to do this?

---

*Obs.: it's a non-compose project.*